# Why folder is not sharing in ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: file-sharing

I want to share my computer's folder beyond the local network, I've installed samaba to access folder from another computers and gives 777 permission and have change owner as well to the folder but it says "You do not have permission to access" while accessing form other computer? please help me